# Keyboard and touchpad not working on new laptop

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, touchpad, lenovo, mousepad

I just got a new Lenovo Legion Y530 and I'm trying to install Ubuntu on it.  However during the install the keyboard and touchpad don't work.  This happened with Ubuntu 18.04 as well as Elementary 0.4.1.

How can I fix this and install Ubuntu? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the operating system using external usb keyboard. After installation the laptop keyboard and trackpad will start worling. If not, you will need to enable external drivers in "Software and updates" application in ubuntu.

Comment: I tried that, too. That didn't work either.